# How to get div number/count in protractor test contained in element

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

My test requires to get the div count/number to what the repeater assigned the value with. I tried to search but none of my findings work.

Array here in `app.js`:

```
 var  rows = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
 var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
 <div ng-repeat = "item in items">
 <span>{{item}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Question: I wanted to get the div number for item that has value span element of 4 or any. How to write this in protractor test with this.

What I used is below but will not work if the value moves to other div in next row:

```
var getnumber = element(by.css=".items").get(4)
```

What is want is :

```
var getnumber = element(by.css=".rows").get("SOMETHING 1,2,3 or 4")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a number - use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
element.all(by.repeater("item in items")).map(function (elm, index) {
    return {
        value: elm.element(by.tagName("span")).getText(),
        index: index
    }
}).then(function (items) {
    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].value === '4') {
            console.log(items[i].index);
        } 
    }
});
```

This would print indexes of elements in the repeater when `span` text is `4`.

---

If you want to filter all repeaters with `span` text being equal to `4`, use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
element.all(by.repeater("item in items")).filter(function (elm) {
   return elm.element(by.tagName("span")).getText().then(function (text) {
       return text === "4";
   });
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I used the second option (filter) and worked like a charm. Cheers.

Comment: @EdiWacs great! Consider making the answer as accepted. Thanks!